# Unable to get If condition to check the value of a textbox field

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, if-statement

I have a form, which allows an Admin to add new users and edit existing user information, all using the same form. When adding a new user, the Admin is presented with a form/ text fields, but when editing a user information, the same form / text fields is populated with the user information.  The Admin wants to be able to edit all the user's info **except for the username**. So I created a condition that test if the value of username text box is not blank or null (for an existing user) then the text box is set to read only. I do not get an error, but after implementing my condition, I'm still able to edit the user name of an existing user.

This is the hypertext for the textbox (snippet):

```
<fieldset style="width:1050px;">
<legend><b>Account Information</b></legend>
    <asp:TextBox ID="textUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</fieldset>
```

The code behind:

```
Protected Sub textUserName_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles textUserName.TextChanged
        If (textUserName.Text.ToString <> "") Then
            textUserName.[ReadOnly] = "true"
        ElseIf (textUserName.Text.ToString <> vbNull) Then
            textUserName.[ReadOnly] = "true"
        End If

    End Sub
```

... could I get some assistance please as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think the condition should be in Page_Load and not Text_Changed.

Comment: It's better to use query string and not to depend on the content of the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReadOnly field takes boolean value, not string.

Try

```
textUserName.ReadOnly = true
```

Comment: But the OP's syntax also works, if the property is enclosed in [].

Comment: ATTN IsabelHM and codingbiz, Thank You, I was able to resolve the issue by placing my condition into the Page_Load. Thanks again